# Keep content hidden based on window size, even after calling load()

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to hide some `div` elements, if the document with is smaller than 500px. That works fine until the first `load()` call happens. I am thinking that document.ready is not called again after load?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".full").hide();
  // checkWidth();
});

setInterval(function() {
  $('#frame').load("https://www.myURL.com/xyz.php .sList, script");
  // checkWidth();
}, 10000);

function checkWidth() {
  var dWidth = $(document).width();
  if (dWidth < 500) {
    $(".full").hide();
  }
}
```

The `load()` is required because the data is changing very often.

I tried also to call the `checkWidth()` function directly after the load function, but it also did not work as expected.

How can I achieve that the `div` is continually hidden?

**Edit**

Finally I got it running with CSS.
But I have also mentioned, that I am using Bootstrap and I had to use `display: none !important;`. Without `!important` `display: none;` was not working.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    div.full{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide content based on screen width, not JS. Aside from better performance, it will also apply to any content added to the DOM after the page has loaded.

Comment: Also note that making an AJAX request to (presumably) your site every 1 second is not a good idea - you're effectively DDOSing yourself if you have more than a few concurrent users. Research websockets if you need to keep the client in sync with server side updates.

Comment: Use window.resize in javascript or resize api if you want to do it with jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Rory, it's 10 seconds and I am the only user the check the status. I will try it with CSS.

Comment: @Vishal, the resize function works fine if I change the size, but it doesn't solve my problem with the load function. After load the `hide()` is not working anymore.